# How do I limit the number of items to be added in listbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a button that adds the value of the textbox Item1.Text into my listbox. If the number of items reached 3, the user won't be able to add anymore. However, my code won't add a single item in the textbox on its first try.

```
       for (int i = 0; i<=3 && i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Item1.Text);
                Item1.Focus();
                Item1.Text = String.Empty;
            }
          messagebox.Show("You've reached the number of items")
```

Comment: Does the listBox1.Count is 0 at the beginning? Because 0 < 0 is not possible

Comment: @d-trump123 what do you think this is doing `i<=3 && i < listBox1.Items.Count` ? -that should clear the things :)

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
if( listBox1.Items.Count <= 3 ){
    listBox1.Items.Add(Item1.Text);
    Item1.Focus();
    Item1.Text = String.Empty;
}else{
    messagebox.Show("You've reached the number of items")
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought of using a simple if else method. Thanks, however it won't stop until 4 items, so I changed the count to <=2.

Comment: Of course it wont stop until 4, because you use `i = 0` and `i <= 3`, and that means you get `i` as 0, 1, 2, 3 what is in total 4 items. As you did you could change to `i <= 2` or the other way would be `i < 3`

Answer (score 2):

`i < listBox1.Items.Count;` your condition in loop will not pass first time because `i==0` and `listbox1.items.count` is also 0, because it is empty.

```
if(listBox1.Items.Count <= 3)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(Item1.Text);
    Item1.Focus();
    Item1.Text = String.Empty;
} 
else
    messagebox.Show("You've reached the number of items")
```